# Chapter font size commands doesn't work

Tags: fonts, chapters, size

There is a lot of pages about this subject, but I didn't find the solution.

I would like to edit a small book with poetry in a5 format.
There is multiple languages (russian, hungarian, swedish...). That's why I need "Nota Serif" font and I'm using xelatex for compiling.

Each chapter is a title of a piece. By example:

```
\chapter*{Sviete Tikhiy}
```

The result is not appropriated because of the too big letters on each chapter title.  The text is 10pt hight and I would like 12pt for the title.  I did not find the solution.

Below is the new code after reading comments from Bernard, Greg and David.

```
\documentclass[headings=small,a5paper,french,10pt]{book}
%\usepackage{graphicx} %for pictures
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\usepackage{verse}

% deleted instructions  as advised by David Carlisle
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{txfonts}

\usepackage[a5paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}

%you should remove the lines for fontenc, inputenc, lmodern, txfonts and textcomp

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{12pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{12pt}{}{\Huge}

\newcommand{\chapfnt}{\fontsize{10}{14}}
\newcommand{\chaptersize}{\fontsize{10}{14}\selectfont}


\pagestyle{plain} %Header is clear, but the footer contains the page number in the center.

%\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
%\usepackage[margin=2cm,top=2.5cm,headheight=16pt,headsep=0.1in,heightrounded]{geometry}

%\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
%\usepackage{color}
%\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.12,0.47,0.87}
%\titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont \bfseries}{\textcolor{darkblue} {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter: #1}}{2pt}{\Huge}
%\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display] {\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont \bfseries}{\textcolor{darkblue} {#1}}{2pt}{\Huge}

\newcommand{\attrib}[1]{\nopagebreak{\raggedleft\footnotesize #1\par}}
\setlength{\stanzaskip}{\baselineskip}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/593104/how-to-use-fontspec-in-details
%https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters

\begin{document}

\author{Parisian Harmonist}
\title{Harmonies du soir}
\date{Janvier 2022}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter


\include{./TeX_files/01}
\include{./TeX_files/02}
\include{./TeX_files/03}
\include{./TeX_files/04}
\include{./TeX_files/05}

\backmatter
% bibliography, glossary and index would go here.

\end{document}
```

Someone has any idea ?

Comment: What would you like to have, exactly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have several contradicting instructions: why loading `lmodern`, `txfonts` and `fontspec`? You will get math in `txfonts` and text in Noto, and the fonts are clashing about letter shapes. By the way, if you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, `inputenc`, `fontenc` and `textcomp` should not be loaded.

Comment: you have not provided any code to show the issue, but note `\newcommand{\chapfnt}{\fontsize{10}{14}}` then`\chapfnt` will noit select any font (that would need `\selectfont`) but as you show no use of this command can not say if that is the cause of your issue.

Comment: why do you select lmodern (which is alrready the default in lualatex and xelatex) only to replace them with tx fonts and then to replace those with noto serif? you should remove the lines for fontenc, inputenc, lmodern, txfonts and textcomp. Then please add to the example so that it has a chapter heading that does not work as you expect.

Comment: what do you mean by modifying the value 110 and 120 ? Your example code does not have 110 or 120 anywhere?

Comment: Thanks to Bernard, Greg and David. I made some modifications as you can see above. But the problem is no resolved.

Comment: I think I get the right way... I was looking for numeric values to tune the font. It seems that the better way is to change "Huge" with "Large" and I can now obtain that I want.